# deploying MERN stack, using github pages and heroku

Tags: reactjs, git, heroku, deployment, mern

I am following this guide to deploy MERN stack app, using heroku and github pages -https://github.com/juliojgarciaperez/deploy-mern

Q1. Do I need to create 2 different repositories, 1 for backend and 1 for frontend to connect to heroku? (t.ex backend repository to the heroku pipeline) I originally developed both backend and frontend under same repository.

Q2. I managed to get the step:3 in guide, and created the new base set up for react app, following the guide mentioned - https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app-buildpack

after generating the react app using this `buildpack` command, I replace the `src` and `public` with what I have written before, also install the dependencies.

but when I run the `git push heroku master` command in terminal,

I get errors saying

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/apprepositorynamehere.git'
```

And when I read the process, it says

```
engines.node (package.json):  unspecified

Cannot find module: 'react-router-dom'. Make sure this package is installed.
You can install this package by running: yarn add react-router-dom.

error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

To solve each problem, I add the `node` with specified version in `package.json`

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "13.7.0"
  },
```

and also ran the `yarn add` command to install the `react-router-dom`
But none of the issues goes away when i re-run the `git push heroku master`.

I originally create the react app and developed in `npm` setting not `yarn`.
I wonder if this is causing the issue where copy pasting my previous `src`?

I wanted to use the github pages bcs it is easy to deal with but If anyone has any other suggestion, to deploy MERN stack app, I am opened to it!

Comment: Please don’t put two questions in one.

Answer (score 0):

To anybody who is looking for an answer to my previous question.

I did not use the `github page` to deploy my MERN stack app,
but used this tutorial 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qdoiwouykAg'

A1. You do not need 2 different repository, but need to configure your `package.json` in both `frontend` and `backend`.

A2. I still see this in terminal, but it does resolve.

```
Resolving node version 12.x...
```